# What does %df represent when formatting a string?

Tags: java, android, string, string-formatting

I am trying to create a VB.net equivalent to an existing Java function. Within this function, a String is formatted to have a certain amount of decimals and digits, but I cannot figure out what the function is doing exactly.

The for loop populates an ArrayList with numerical values between a given `min/max`. Depending on the parameter `dec2disp`, the numerical values are adjusted to show a certain number of decimal digits.

The Java code is as follows:

```
    for( double d = min; d <= max; d+=inc ) {
        if((m_flags&dispZeroAsOff)!=0 && d==0){
            vList.add(m_offString);
        }else{
            String fmt=String.format("%%.%df", dec2disp);
            String temp = String.format(fmt, d);
            vList.add(temp + unit);
        }
    }
```

The line that confuses me is `String.format("%%.%df", dec2disp);`. I have found explanations for `%d` and `%f`, but cannot find anything anywhere about `%df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String fmt=String.format("%%.%df", dec2disp);

This line generates a valid format specifier for the number of decimal places requested by dec2disp (which replaces the "%d" in the "%%.%df" resulting in something like fmt="%.2f")

---

String temp = String.format(fmt, d);

This uses the format specifier stored in fmt to display the value of d with the correct number of decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

> I have found explanations for %d and %f, but cannot find anything
>   anywhere about %df.

It stands for `DecimalFormat`.

```
java.lang.Object

   ↳    java.text.Format

       ↳    java.text.NumberFormat

           ↳    java.text.DecimalFormat
```

> A concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats decimal numbers. It
>   has a variety of features designed to make it possible to parse and
>   format numbers in any locale, including support for Western, Arabic,
>   or Indic digits. It also supports different flavors of numbers,
>   including integers ("123"), fixed-point numbers ("123.4"), scientific
>   notation ("1.23E4"), percentages ("12%"), and currency amounts
>   ("$123"). All of these flavors can be easily localized.

Reference - [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

**NOTE:**

If you are interested in different string formatters then follow the final class [Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.util.Formatter
```

Comment: Do you know of anywhere I can find an example of the class being used like this? I had looked into `DecimalFormat` but I can still not come up with any examples using something similar to `%%.%df`

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is the only part of the string pattern that is relevant to formatting. The `f` is just a character literal, the dot as well and the double percent sign is also a literal, but escaped.

In the end, this pattern does not actually format decimal numbers at all. Here is a simple test to prove it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%%.%df", i));
}
```

Output:

```
%.0f
%.1f
%.2f
%.3f
%.4f
%.5f
%.6f
%.7f
%.8f
%.9f
```

If `i` was a float or a double, it would throw an `IllegalFormatConversionException`, because `%d` can only be applied on whole numbers.